# Multiplex webcams feeds into one feed

Tags: java, webcam, feed, multiplexing

I want to develop an application to combine the streams of multiple webcams into one stream. It's an idea flying in my head since 3months.

The application will take as input  feeds from up to 2 webcams, combine them into a single feed (split-screen) or choose one at a time, and then send the resulting feed to a program such as Skype.

Here is a flowchart:
[image]

There a here 3 steps to do :

- get feeds from USB webcams
- combine feeds  into one
- send result to Skype (create a virtual cam detectable by Skype)

What is the best way to go about doing this ?

Are there special kind of processing to do ?

I'm good in Java.